# How to extract vectors from map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon-creation, feature-extraction, polygonize

I am trying to extract building footprints from a raster map (as shown in the example below). Please note that the maps are out of copyright, have been scanned and georectified by a library and have been provided to me for exactly this purpose.

[image: Scaled example - original geotif available on request]

So far I have been using the [NYPL Map-Vectorizer](https://github.com/NYPL/map-vectorizer) which works by first adjusting the brightness/contrast of the image, then setting a colour threshold to extract a black and white image, which in turn is processed using gdal_polygonize.py (followed by some simplification and removal of roads).

The issue is that this gives polygons of the *inside* of the building. Terrace buildings end up with a gap between them.

**How can I post-process to remove the gap between the terrace buildings? Is there an altogether better method for extracting building footprints from this map?**

Note: Solutions need to be able to run as a script. I'm able to test proposed techniques in QGIS.

Comment: Can you share some sample data with footprints and gaps? It would be so much faster to start making trials with your real data.

Comment: Sure. I've uploaded to GDrive: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6J5ZA1hu93bSXlTSE9GU3Q5bzQ&usp=sharing Here you will find the original geotif (cropped.tif), the current NYPL script output (the zip shapefile), the intermediate tiff image, and a png example that shows that I can tweak the image manipulation to get a better input to the vectorizer process. (Note: Tiff files are 40mb and should be uploaded by the time you've read this)

Comment: I made a very quick trial with OpenJUMP topology tools and I have a feeling that this is not going to be trivial task at all. I could remove majority of gaps but the buildings tend to have odd shapes instead of rectangles. By using a small buffer (0.5 m) before cleaning the topology made result a bit better but not good still. Somehow I feel that for a good looking result the building outlines from the original scans should be extracted as well and the polygons should be snapped to this outline layer when the gaps are removed.

Comment: The image shown is fairly *pasty* and dull. You will probably get better results if you adjust the contrast so it looks more monochromatic. This is a visual thing so it is best done interactively case by case (i.e. not one setting for all) in a package like photoshop; if you are editing outside of spatially aware programs remember to keep a world file as the save may overwrite the GeoTags.

Comment: Yep, the image here is the original, but it's easy to get a monochromatic image from it (in fact that's what the NYPL Map-Vectorizer starts by doing). See the link to GDrive above for some test files. So any ideas how to eliminate the gap between terraced buildings?

Comment: Is the point to get approximate build up area or the buildings polygons must "look good" as in the map? In the second case I think the only proper way is manual vectorization. The only thing I can think of is some graphical software has optimised tools to vectorize line shapes to lines which could be than converted to polygons (or used to clip polygon). Looking at all letters etc. in the map there still would be big amount of manual work to make it clean.

Answer (score 1):

For rough build up areas:

1. Using python load image and scipy/numpy to:

   - smooth it to get "uniform darker colour" for buildings
   - reclassify image colours to change building from light gray to black

For the example image the result processed by python script looks like this:
[image: processed]

2. vectorize this adjusted image

Some graphics and CAD software has good tools to convert technical drawings lines to polylines and can be scriptable but it is far from perfect and needs much additional manual work:

[image: polylines]

At the end for these kind of tasks if you need good quality vector polygons you need to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

As per user30184 I gave FME a try with a buffer (again 0.5m gave the best result) and the propriatary 'SliverRemover' to clean the result. Looks okay but suitability depends on the ultimate purpose of the output. [image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  It looks like you are offering a FME Answer to a Question with a QGIS requirement.  Sometimes you will see people downvote in cases like this but since you are new I am hoping everyone will overlook that while you settle into the protocols of this site.

Comment: It's a suggestion for an alternative tool, nothing more, which the OP can ignore as desired.

Comment: I'm happy to receive answers that propose alternate solutions, but in this case I don't know what FME is? I don't suppose you still have to output data so I can view this with the map in the background? Thanks

Comment: FME should be this software: http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-desktop/