# Coverting TIFF file by Raster Calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon-creation, polygonize, feature-extraction

My ultimate goal is same as [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97909/how-to-extract-vectors-from-map-using-qgis?rq=1)
Here is my steps:

1. The image is created using Python and saved as PNG format:

[image]

2. Import the image into QGIS using [Georeferencing](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html) tool and saved as TIFF:
   [image]
3. Reclassified the image value using `Raster -> Raster Calculator` in order to use processes such as r.thin and r.to.vect later according to [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251360/converting-raster-to-vector-by-generating-center-lines/251361#251361):
   [image]
4. But the result is weird:
   [image: wrong result]

Not sure what's wrong here.
Or are there any other solutions?